# GKE jumping metrics, scaling up and down

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, metrics, hpa

After upgrade GKE (Google Kubernetes Engine) to version `1.16.8-gke.15` from 1.15.9 we are seeing strange metrics for one workload with 3 replicas (another workloads with one or two replicas are fine). Creation date of pod is still same (no changes based on graph). Node resources are enough. Can you please help somehow? Thanks.

[IMG - Workload jumping metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0vQL.png)

[IMG - Workloads system objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0ry8.png)

Comment: The graphs look like the number of pods keeps scaling up and down which is why the total requests and limits go up and down in that pattern. Do you have nodes scaling up and down or are nodes spinning up and crashing frequently?

Comment: @patrickw no actually nothiing is scaling up and down (nodes, pods...) it looks like graph render issue only, but I would like to be sure.

Comment: This could be related to alignment issues on 1.16 when exporting metrics, therefore breaking graphs. Once I find out more I will do my best to update here.

Comment: It looks like your issue is similar to this: [Issuetracker.google.com: Issues: 158039186](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158039186). Am I correct to say you are experiencing the same issues as in the link?

Comment: @danyL that would be great, thanks.

Comment: @DawidKruk yes i think its exactly the same. Thanks